# Change jQuery element toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this example with a div which `show / hide` from the top, but I need it from the bottom to the top, I was trying to change some code, but I couldn't, and I didn't find any example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Slide Panel

```
<div id="panel">
    <!-- you can put content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: _jquery,html.html5,java_ This isn't a good question title.

Comment: Don't quite understand, the dive slides open from the top to bottom and slides closed from bottom to top. What do you want to do? http://jsfiddle.net/FLE3z/

Comment: use `animate()` if you want to change the direction of your `DIV`

Comment: I didn't understand your issue .. http://jsfiddle.net/E9f6K/1/

Comment: hi plz check this link http://followtherainbow.com.au/ 
view the bottom right of map. you see the plus button .I hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the animate effect(http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and change the height of the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
if($('#panel1').height=='0')
$("#panel1").animate({height:"140px"},{duration:1000});
else
$("#panel1").animate({height:"0px"},{duration:1000});

    });
});
```

this will act as a toggle as well as amimate from bottom

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [slide effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) provided by the jQuery UI. It allows you to define the direction as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use animate option in jquery, here is the code

HTML

```
<button class="btn-slide">Some Text</button>
<div id="box">
<div id="panel">Sample Text here<br/> Sample Text here<br/>Sample Text here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box
{
height: 100px;
width:200px;
position:relative;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
#panel
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
width:200px;
height:20px;
border: 1px solid red;
display:none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
var panelH = $('#box').innerHeight();
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
$("#panel").stop(1).show().height(0).animate({height: panelH},500);
});
});
```